# Views Infinite Scroll pager conflicts with Comments pager

Tags: views

After adding a block with Views Infinite Scroll pager under node pages, an unexpected pager appears under comments. Is there anything should I do to remove this pager?

[image: Wrong pager under comments!]

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: @NoSssweat Drupal 7 + Views Infinite Scroll

Comment: That is weird, what does that pager control? the comments or the infinite scroll view? Click on `2` and see what you get. You can always hide that pager with CSS.